# Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut to run a script in Terminator?

Tags: bash, gnome, shortcut-keys

I am fairly new to Ubuntu. I am currently trying to create a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) to execute the script below in terminator. I got this shortcut to work with the gnome terminal via Settings → Keyboard Shortcuts and then using the command:

```bsh
gnome-terminal -e /home/name/scripts
```

Is it possible to have the same shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) execute the same script but in Terminator rather than GNOME Terminal? I use bash.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Opening K&R folder";

cd Desktop/'C K&R'/Chapter1

echo "=====files=====";

ls
```

Comment: `terminator -x script` should work. Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Kulfy I used this command: ```terminator -x /home/name/scripts/KandR.sh```. When pressing the keyboard shortcut, terminator opens up for a split second and then crashes. When I check the Title section for the crash report, it says: ```terminator crashed with TypeError in spawn_child(): Item 0: Must be number, not str```.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you install terminator?

Comment: @Kulfy I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64 bit, with GNOME version 3.36.2. I'm pretty sure I used  ```sudo apt install terminator``` to get terminator.